# Typescript path module resolution is not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, tsconfig, modular

I am using Express JS and Typescript. I am trying to implement a modular pattern.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
 "include": ["src"],
 "exclude": ["node_modules"],
 "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es2016",
   "module": "commonjs",
   "rootDir": "./src",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   "baseUrl": "./src",
   "paths": {
     "@src/*": ["src/*"]
   },
   "outDir": "./dist",
   "esModuleInterop": true,
   "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
   "strict": true,
   "skipLibCheck": true
 }
}
```

**src/modules/stuedent/student.interface.ts**

```
export type UserName = {
    firstName: string;
    //...
  };
  
  export type Guardian = {
    fatherName: string;
    //...
  };
  
  export type LocalGuardian = {
    name: string;
    //...
  };
  
  export type Student = {
    id: string;
    name: UserName;
    guardian: Guardian;
    localGuardian: LocalGuardian;
    //...
  };
```

**src/modules/stuedent/student.module.ts**

```
import { Guardian, LocalGuardian, Student, UserName } from './student.interface';
```

The above  works fine

```
import { Guardian, LocalGuardian, Student, UserName } from '@src/student/student.interface';
```

The above shows error: *Cannot find module '@src/student/student.interface' or its corresponding type declarations.*

I want to perform the imports using @src.

How do i do it with modular path resolution?

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `baseUrl` to `./src` means TypeScript starts looking for files from the `src` folder. When we then use `@src/` to import files, TypeScript tries to find them within the `src` folder, but that's not where the folder is located. By changing the `baseUrl` to just `./`, TypeScript starts searching from the project's main folder. This way, when we use `@src/` in our imports, TypeScript knows to search the entire project for the `src` folder.

```
{
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

So, when you import files, you can use the `@src` shortcut like this:

```
import { Guardian, LocalGuardian, Student, UserName } from '@src/modules/student'
```

Comment: Hi, I tried "baseUrl": "./",. it's not working. You can check this from below github repo:
https://github.com/Apu-Emdad/node_express_starter_pack/tree/import-error

Comment: I have cloned your repo and everything seems to be working fine.
Have you changed the import url to `@src/modules/student/student.interface` in the `student.model.ts` file? I don't get any errors. Let me know if you the error persists